# Design pattern to follow in the following case

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, webkit, gtk

I'm creating one tab based C++ application using GTK+ toolkit and Webkit for learning purpose. I've created following files

- Main.cpp => Application entry-point
- MainWindow.cpp/.h        => MainWindow which creates toolbar object, Notebook, Statusbar
- Toolbar.cpp/.h           => toolbar items like back, forward, urlbar, stop/refresh,
- NotebookContainer.cpp/.h => for creating new tab etc
- TabWebView.cpp/.h        => for creating tab(label+close button), web-view etc.

Now I want to communicate in between toolbar and TabView class. So when any event occur on toolbar I can do the action in webview.cpp and some event trigger from webview I can do the required on toolbar (like enabling/disabling stop button)

Which design pattern should I need to follow in this scenario?

NOTE: GTK+ is c based library.

Comment: I guess you are search for Command pattern.
I use it in my TD game, when i want to execute the command on the map, what was chosed in the user interface (like: BuildTower, CastSpell etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you are asking the wrong question.  Rather than asking what design pattern to follow, I would suggest you ask what the most idiomatic way to solve your problem is.

All too often the wors design failures I have to fix come from a young coder whose approach is "what design pattern can I use here?", or "How can I use more design patterns".

Studying design patterns is useful in providing a vocabulary for discussing your designs, and they are useful in inspiring and informing your design choices, but your design approach should always be "what the simplest, cleanest, most effective, idiomatic approach here".  Sometimes the answer to that question will be a design pattern.  Sometimes it will a part of a design pattern, and sometimes it will be something much simpler -- typically an idiom in the language or library you are working with.

I don't do a lot of GUI programming, so I can't help much with your concrete question.  For the problem you are presenting, it sounds like you want to use GTK's signal/slot framework.  Alternatively boost offers similar functionality if you want to get familiar with boost's tools.  Both would be idiomatic approaches to what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, I do keep this in mind. I've started writing the code, but then I realize that I have some big problem in the approach because I was passing references all around. I trap in a situation where I have one toolbar and many view I need to update the toolbar as per the current selection of view. Someone here suggested me that MVC is what I need. Let's see how far I will go, I learning to write clean, abstract and meaning code.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is some along the lines of an observer pattern:
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

and more generally something like Model-View-Controller or Presentation-Abstraction-Control models:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation%E2%80%93abstraction%E2%80%93control

You might want to have a look at the Qt Signal/Slot implementation also:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: OP uses GTK+, so he already have perfect signals/slots with type safety and no runtime overhead. Using qt signals will be large step backward!

Comment: I think MVC is what I need. Because I've one toolbar(toolbar's items) and many tabs. On the change of tab I've to update the toolbar and on action of toolbar I've to update the web view also.

Comment: Any sample for implementing MVC?